tcbraster box width change
How can I make the width of the box on the left shorter and the right longer, so that the overall length fits the page?
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster equal height]
\begin{tcolorbox[empty,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm]
word
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[empty,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm]
definition
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}


Hi Clx and welcome to tex exchange! Could you provide a minimal working example (MWE)? A MWE is the shortest possible document to reproduce your problem. In your case, you just have to add a minimal preamble and the \begin{document} and \end{document} commands. This greatly helpes others in helping you, so you get quicker and better replies.

See the documentation of the key /tcb/raster force size=true|false in the tcolorbox manual. You need to set raster force size=false for the raster and to use add to width for the boxes.
